# Expandable listview scrolls when using robotium to click on a image in listview

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robotium

When I am using Robotium to click on the image on the first item of an expandable listview like this:

```
ListView listview = getCurrentListView().getChildAt(1); //get feed listview.
for(ImageView view : solo.getCurrentImageViews(listview))
{
   if(view.getId() == R.id.image) //all images in the feed listview shares the same ID.
   {
      solo.clickonview(view);
      break;  //get the first image then break the loop.
   }
}
```

The expandable listview scrolls. 
using logcat, I am sure, I have got the first image. but when solo.clickonview, it doesn't work, and the listview began to scroll along to the last one. 
Why does it happen?
Are there some ways to finish the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below method before clicking and set scroll to false:

```
waitForView(View view, int timeout, boolean scroll)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it click on this image?
I'm not sure, if you provide correct parent for getCurrentImageViews.

try to use this:

```
for (View v : solo.getCurrentImageViews()) {
     if (v.getId() == R.id.image)
          solo.clickonview(v);
}
```

Comment: I also tried this, but it fails too. I can get the image on the first listview item, but when solo.clickonview, it seems doesn't work, and the listview begin to scroll along to the last item.